# Mocha TS tests fail with `npm test` but not if run directly

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js

In my nodejs project (written in Typescript) I can run my tests with this command:

```
mocha --compilers ts:ts-node/register,tsx:ts-node/register
```

and they succeed. I also used this command in my package.json file so that

```
npm test
```

runs them the same way, however in this case I get:

```
Mikes-iMac:antlr4-graps mike$ npm test

> mocha --compilers ts:ts-node/register,tsx:ts-node/register

module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'ts-node/register'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
```

My package.json file contains:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --compilers ts:ts-node/register,tsx:ts-node/register"
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^3.4.34",
    "@types/mocha": "^2.2.32",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.40",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "mocha": "^2.5.3",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3",
    "vscode": "^1.0.0"
  },
```

What is the correct variant to run mocha via npm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that no matter what, but `npm run <script>` in general and `npm test` in particular will run command using `/bin/sh`, not your current shell, which is likely different.

Since you don't have `ts-node` in your dependencies, I assume it's installed globally. Depending on how you install Node.js, `/bin/sh` may end up using different Node.js installation than your current shell and therefore not have same globally installed package.

If I'm right these two commands will give different results:

```
$ which node
$ /bin/sh -c 'which node'
```

Two possible solutions:

1. Add `ts-node` to `devDependencies` of you project and `npm install`.
2. Ensure, that `/bin/sh` uses same installation of Node.js, as you current shell.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head. I thought I had ts-node as dev-dependency but didn't check this actually. After adding it, everything started working also with npm.

Comment: Happy it helped you ;)